# Problemas con el posicionamiento de elementos de un gráfico en python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy haciendo un programa que dibuje círculos sobre el perímetro de un rectángulo que a su vez está dentro de otro rectángulo. Los círculos en el eje X deben de estar equidistantes y cubrir toda la longitud de la base del rectángulo. Para ello, he escrito el siguiente código en python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Datos de entrada
ancho = 20 # ancho 
peralte = 40 # peralte 
recubrimiento = 5 # recubrimiento
diam_barras = 1 # diámetro de las barras 

# Cálculo de las dimensiones 
h = peralte - recubrimiento*2
b = ancho - recubrimiento*2


num_barras_x = 4 # número de barras o círculos en el eje x


# Calculamos la separación entre las barras o círculos en el eje x
separacion_x = b / (num_barras_x + 1)


# Gráfico
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim([-ancho/2, ancho/2])
ax.set_ylim([0, peralte])
ax.set_aspect('equal')

# Dibujo de la sección rectangular (-5, 5) (5, 35)
rect = plt.Rectangle((-b/2, recubrimiento), b, h, linewidth=1, edgecolor='k', facecolor='none')
ax.add_patch(rect)

# Dibujo de las barras o círculos en el eje x
y1 = peralte - recubrimiento - diam_barras/2 
y2 = recubrimiento + diam_barras/2 
# Calculamos la posición de los círculos en el eje x
posiciones_x = [-b/2 + (i+1)*separacion_x for i in range(num_barras_x)]
for x in posiciones_x:
    circ1 = plt.Circle((x, y1), diam_barras/2, linewidth=1, edgecolor='k', facecolor='none')
    ax.add_patch(circ1)
    circ2 = plt.Circle((x, y2), diam_barras/2, linewidth=1, edgecolor='k', facecolor='none')
    ax.add_patch(circ2)

# Mostrar el gráfico
plt.show()
```

Obteniendo lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría modificar mi código para que los círculos se posicionen en las esquinas y cubran la longitud de la base (-5, 5) del rectángulo de manera equidistante?

Answer (score 1):

Hice algunos cambios en tu código los cuales presentaré aquí:

1. Para hacer que los círculos cubrieran la longitud del rectángulo de manera equidistante, modifiqué la variable `separacion_x` restando a uno `num_barras_x`, esto hace que la separación entre los círculos sea la misma. Parecerá contra intuitivo esto pero recuerda que un circulo ya se encuentra posicionado en una esquina, por lo tanto solo debes calcular la distancia restante para llenar la base del rectángulo de los tres restantes:

```py
separacion_x = b / (num_barras_x - 1)
```

2. Adicional al punto anterior, también modifiqué la variable `posiciones_x` haciendo que el contador `i` empiece desde 1 y no desde 2:

```
posiciones_x = [-b/2 + (i)*separacion_x for i in range(num_barras_x)]
```

3. Respecto a cubrir las esquinas, esto lo entendí a mi concepto a que los círculos tengan su centro en las esquinas de los rectángulos. Para esto modifiqué las variables `y1` y `y2` quitando la resta del `diam_barras/2`. Recuerda que el la posición del círculo se encuentra definida desde su centro.

```py
y1 = peralte - recubrimiento #Valor calculado: 35
y2 = recubrimiento #Valor calculado: 5
```

De esa manera, obtendríamos el siguiente gráfico:
[image: Gráfico resultante]

En el gráfico puede parecer que los círculos de las esquinas se encuentran desfasados pero no es así, aquí una muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y eso sería todo, espero te sea de ayuda :)

Comment: Del código original, he agregado tu modificación a la variable separacion_x y modificado el ciclo a: `y1 = peralte - recubrimiento - diam_barras/2
y2 = recubrimiento + diam_barras/2
for i in range(num_barras_x):
    x = -b/2 + diam_barras/2 + i*separacion_x 
    circ1 = plt.Circle((x, y1), diam_barras/2, linewidth=1, edgecolor='k', facecolor='none')
    ax.add_patch(circ1)
    circ2 = plt.Circle((x, y2), diam_barras/2, linewidth=1, edgecolor='k', facecolor='none')
    ax.add_patch(circ2) ` sin embargo el ultimo par de círculos está por fuera y no dentro de la esquina como el primer par.

Comment: Vale @DanielRico. Ya veo como lo necesitabas hacer. En tal caso solo cambia la variable `separacion_x = (b-1) / (num_barras_x - 1)` y ya todos los circulos quedarían dentro del rectángulo